# SQL - Agrupar valores según distintos campos

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy practicando con sql server y tengo el siguiente problema:

- Tengo una tabla en una base de datos con las siguientes columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Necesito generar una consulta con la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde "Valor producto" es la suma de la columna "Valor" pero agrupado por la columna "Producto" y "Valor categoría" es la suma de la columna "Valor" pero agrupado por la columna "Categoría". Puedo generar las consultas por separado pero me cuesta trabajo poder contener ambas en una consulta.

Cualquier idea de como resolver el problema es mas que agradecido.

Answer (score 4):

Revisando en un foro llegue a la respuesta a mi duda, la dejo por acá por si alguien mas llega a tenerla.

La query quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
    distinct(Producto), 
    categoria, 
    SUM(valor) OVER(PARTITION BY Producto) 'Valor producto', 
    SUM(valor) OVER(PARTITION BY categoria) 'Valor categoria' 
from Ejemplo.dbo.Tabla_Agrupados
```

La solución viene al utilizar la función OVER(PARTITION BY ) para agrupar en vez del group by.

Dejo el link del foro con la repuesta por si alguien quiere obtener mas detalles:
https://www.sqlshack.com/es/descripcion-general-de-la-clausula-partition-by-de-sql/

Gracias a quienes revisaron la pregunta, espero que ayude la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Dejo una opción que, en teoría, debería ser más eficiente porque realiza menos trabajo al hacer un "pre-agregado". Esto considera que un producto solo puede pertenecer a una categoría. En caso contrario, se debe utilizar una solución distinta.

```
WITH ctePreAgregado AS(
    SELECT Producto,
           Categoria,
           SUM(Valor) Valor
    FROM Ejemplo.dbo.Tabla_Agrupados
    GROUP BY Producto, Categoria
)
SELECT Producto,
       Categoria,
       Valor AS ValorProducto,
       SUM( Valor) OVER( PARTITION BY Categoria) AS ValorCategoria
FROM ctePreAgregado;
```